# Rewrite wordpress url to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain

i have a wordpress site let just call it testing.com
with a page url called blog/ which can access via testing.com/blog

i am using NGINX as the web server.

How do i rewrite the testing.com/blog to blog.testing.com with all its content still intact?

//edit

in this case, /blog is a page in the wordpress and not the wordpress itself, only that page and all the link inside the page would be rewrite to the subdomain and nothing else

example:
inside of the blog.testing.com there was 2 more link such as:
 1. older post
    (original link will be testing.com/blog/page/2 and change it to blog.testing.com/page/2)
 1. read more on each post
    (original link will be testing.com/2017/05/testpost1 and change it to blog.testing.com/2017/05/testpost1)

//end of edit

so as to say as if i am opening testing.com/blog in blog.testing.com

i have tried rewrite and proxy pass

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    rewrite ^/admin(.*) http://blog.testing.com$uri permanent;
 }
```

with the above block

the result is same as return the url only and not with the supposed content.

or is it not possible to do so?

Comment: if you want to use testing.com as blog.testing.com register a sub-domain of testing.com with name of blog.testing.com and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi assuming that you don't want to keep the URL testing.com/blog at all and instead want to use the subdomain blog.testing.com then effectively what you want to achieve is a WordPress migration. There are a number of ways you can achieve a migration, depending on how technically able you are. The easiest way is probably to install and use a WordPress migration plug in such as WordPress Duplicator or WordPress Move. Please take a backup of your files AND database before you start.

The official WordPress guide to migration can be found at https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

In short you would create the subdomain, then move (migrate) the site that's currently at testing.com/blog to the subdomain blog.testing.com

If the subdomain directory is to be left at /blog and you are just pointing the subdomain to that directory, then you might be able to do what you need to do just by updating the database to reset all the internal URLs in the WordPress database. In this case you could consider using https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

This is what I tend to use when migrating sites from test to live. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for answering !!
actually, the /blog was just a page inside the wordpress, not the whole site
only that page would be redirect to the subdomain and not the whole wordpress. sorry, i should have make it more clearer in my question part.

Comment: Ah OK! You probably did say that and I misunderstood!